C# Selenium ChromeDriver Leaking memory
I'm seeking assistance as I've noticed that selenium chromeDriver in c# has not properly been releasing memory. I've been using RamMap to track memory usage. When not running the following scripts, memory usage does not steadily increase.
Running the scripts below within task scheduler causes memory within the "Unused-Active" entry of RamMap to increase on every run. I've confirmed there are no active chromedriver or chrome processes within resource monitor, task manager, or RamMap. Selenium.WebDriver v4.23.0. Chrome and ChromeDriver v127.
Screenshots of RamMap for reference, as seen the "Unused-Active" entry rises significantly after about 5 minutes of running the scripts. This value does not rise when the scripts are not running.
Root of concern as shown in the screenshots is "Unused - Active" goes from 7000KB to 50000KB in the span of 5 minutes. Over the course of 24 hours, if that continues, that's an increase of nearly 12384000KB or about 12 GB. This is causing a major performance problem as after a week of running, the machine gets over 80% usage of RAM that's just unused but still considered "Active".
Before running scripts (After reboot) - Value does not increase:

10 minutes of downtime - no scripts running

15 scheduled tasks launching the console app every minute for 5 minutes - Value increased significantly

10 minutes of downtime - stop the scripts from running

Reproducible code I've tried: (Create C# console app and configure the project to run via 15 scheduled tasks in Task Scheduler every minute.)
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
namespace ChromeBotTest
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (ChromeDriver? chromeDriver = new()) //using statement for automatic disposal
            {
                await Task.Delay(3000); //allow chrome to open for some short time
                chromeDriver.Close(); //close all windows
                chromeDriver.Quit(); //quit to fully close browser and release resources
            }
        }
    }
}

using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
namespace ChromeBotTest
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (ChromeDriver? chromeDriver = new()) //using statement for automatic disposal
            {
                await Task.Delay(3000); //allow chrome to open for some short time
                chromeDriver.Quit(); //quit to fully close browser and release resources
            }
        }
    }
}

using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
namespace ChromeBotTest
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            ChromeDriver chromeDriver = new(); 
            await Task.Delay(3000); //allow chrome to open for some short time
            chromeDriver.Quit(); //quit to fully close browser and release resources
        }
    }
}

using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
namespace ChromeBotTest
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            ChromeDriver? chromeDriver = new();
            await Task.Delay(3000); //allow chrome to open for some short time
            chromeDriver.Close(); //close all windows
            chromeDriver.Quit(); //quit to fully close browser and release resources
            chromeDriver?.Dispose(); //dispose incase chromeDriver is not properly disposed
            chromeDriver = null; //set to null to ensure its cleared
        }
    }
}

    using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
    namespace ChromeBotTest
    {
        public class Program
        {
            private static async Task Main(string[] args)
            {
                ChromeDriver? chromeDriver = new();
                await Task.Delay(3000); //allow chrome to open for some short time
                chromeDriver.Close(); //close all windows
                chromeDriver.Quit(); //quit to fully close browser and release resources
                chromeDriver?.Dispose(); //dispose incase chromeDriver is not properly disposed
                chromeDriver = null; //set to null to ensure its cleared
                await Task.Delay(2000); //allow 2 second delay
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers(); //clean up garabage collection
                GC.Collect();
                await Task.Delay(10000); //wait 10 seconds to allow garbage collection sufficent time to execute
            }
        }
    }


just use driver.quit()... let GC do its work automatically.  You don't need .close() first (that's mainly for closing a single tab when you have multiple), don't need to dispose or use using... don't need to manually use GC.  I would compare your results with a manual launch and close of the browser (I suspect this is all browser related).  The only difference with the Selenium default session would be the temporary directories/profile/file(s) created and then cleaned up on quit.  Browser's GC logic is fairly complicated and it's hard to predict when it deals with things marked for disposal.

This did not fix - updated initial post of test code

Does this chrome driver run in a separate process? Or does the memory increase when running the process a second time? I would generally advice using a memory profiler, but that is mostly helpful to find managed leaks. I suspect this leaks unmanaged memory, and no amount of garbage collection will help. But it is not clear to me what the problem is, if you dispose everything you have created your responsibilities should be fulfilled.

Tracked it down to Trellix/Mcafee holding zombied handles to the terminated processes using RamMap and https://github.com/randomascii/blogstuff/tree/main/FindZombieHandles

Unless this is causing a performance problem, I'm not sure you have a problem to solve. The .NET Framework does not release memory just because the garbage collector runs. The runtime will keep allocated memory, so the operating system will still see that memory as being used (although it might be considered inactive). Only if the system runs out of unused memory will the .NET runtime start giving up its unused memory. This is expected behavior, if I remember correctly.
Some additional resources:

Automatic memory management
Fundamentals of garbage collection
.NET Free memory usage (how to prevent overallocation / release memory to the OS)

To be honest, the numbers you have highlighted in the screenshots do not look all that different, unless I'm missing something...

going from 7000KB to 50000KB in the span of 5 minutes is a large difference. Over the course of 24 hours if that continues, that's an increase of nearly 12384000KB or about 12 GB. This is causing a major performance problem as after a week of running, the machine gets over 80% usage of ram that's just unused but still considered "Active". I typically reboot the machine once it gets to 85% as other processes begin to slow down such as IIS.

the key is "if that continues"... it's fairly normal for it to reach a sort of plateau and level out at a certain point.  You want to utilize memory as it'll be faster than paging to disk.  If over time it never stops rising or starts slowing things down because it starts paging to disk you might consider installing more ram.  Browsers are also resource hogs when it comes to threading/processes as modern browsers separate all domains into different processes so it could also be number of processes that are slowing things down hogging time slices.

You might also want to check task manager for orphaned chromedriver.exe processes.  It's not likely to be the cause of high memory usage, but it's worth a check.  (chromedriver is bound to fail at some point and not always gracefully)

Thanks for the input @browsermator . I've confirmed that there are no hanging/orphaned chromedriver.exe or chrome.exe processes. This machine that is referenced in the screenshots has 96GB of RAM. For purposes of testing I've been running the tests on that machine but our production machine has 144 GB of RAM which sees the same issue. We have several other scripts that run automatically using .NET which don't cause this resource consumption. We've already seen that entry in RamMap get to over 90GB

@freyfrey01, that is suspicious. We run our tests on Windows Server (something recent) and we run tests overnight. We have 16GB of RAM on that server, and it handles a 12 hour test run just fine. But we run tests in batches. We don't run 4,000 selenium tests in a row. Selenium tests marshal a lot of machinery. You might just need to periodically kill processes.

you might check/update video card drivers... I saw that mentioned as a cause of this when I googled. (rammap doesn't know what's using that memory so it's listed as "unused")

The only other thing I can think of would be the drivermanager because it does some I/O file download stuff.  (that kind of thing you would want to dispose of, so maybe they're not doing that properly) You might try setting paths to chromedriver and options.setBinary (path to browser) explicitly to rule that out.

Thanks for the comments @browsermator, I confirmed it wasn't video card drivers by using the Microsoft Process Explorer application which does give the driver RAM usage (Referenced in other forums). I also tested the setBinary (seems deprecated to options.BinaryLocation=...) options.BinaryLocation = @"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe";
ChromeDriver chromeDriver = new(options);
which provided the same results

I suppose it might be worth trying with Geckodriver/Firefox to rule out some bug in chromedriver.  If you type to IWebDriver you can use same code but initialization.

@browsermator tried with Firefox driver and same results. Is anyone able to reproduce?

I think this probably rules out the Selenium side of things.  (but do be sure to get rid of all GC handling and dispose calls... let GC do it's thing automatically)  Running 15 instances of .NET core + Selenium + a webdriver + a browser in one minute seems a bit much.  Run 1 instance and check that it exits properly after a few minutes.  (exit command called?)  Since .NET core is it's own run-time maybe rammap lists its resources as unused.

could it be as simple as that?  No .exit()?
